# Is there any way to get the position of image w.r.t. text in .docx with text wrapping other than inline in ooxml?

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml, saxparser, word-2007

When an image is placed in a word 2007 document with text wrapping other than 'inline', the position of the image with respect to text is not reflected in the document.xml. Only I am able to get the horizontal and vertical position offset from column and paragraph. I am not able to figure out whether the image comes in between two words of text or after/before the words. Is there a way to know that, suppose I want to represent the document in html? I am using sax parser and some part of Apache-poi to parse the .docx. Help is appreciated if anyone is conversant with these technologies.